# Writing to a file and maintain the syntax

Tags: python

Started with python after a long time:

Basically I am trying to read a line from a file:

```
MY_FILE                     ='test1.hgx'
```

Eventually I want to change this test1.hgx with:

```
test1_para1_para2_para3.hgx
```

Where para1,23 are the parameters I want to write.

I wrote a code below

```
add_name= '%s'%(filename)+'_'+'%s'%(para1)+'_'+'%s'%(para2)+'_'+'%s'%(para3)+'.hgx'
print "added_name:",add_name

with open(filename) as f:  lines = f.read().splitlines()
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith(' MY_FILE'):

            f.write(line.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + "\'%s'\n"%add_name)
        else:
            f.write(line + '\n')
f.close
```

The above code works as expected and writes out when I execute the python code once:

```
MY_FILE                     ='test1_01_02_03.hgx'
```

However when I run the python code once again for the second time it eats up the '=' and writes the following:

```
MY_FILE                     'test1_01_02_03.hgx'
```

Can I add something to my existing code that would always preserve the writing of the 'test1_01_02_03.hgx'. I think there is problem with :

```
f.write(line.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + "\'%s'\n"%add_name)
```

However I am not able to figure out the problem. Any ideas would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
        f.write(line.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + "\'%s'\n"%add_name)
```

to

```
        f.write(line.rsplit('=', 1)[0] + "=\'%s'\n"%add_name)
```

Incidentally, are you sure that in the original file, there wasn't a space after the `=`? If there is no space after the `=`, this code will always eat up the `=`. If there is a space, it won't eat it up until the second time the code is run.

Comment: Thank you. Yes in the original file there was a space after "=". Your suggestion however solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `fileinput` module. Also, use `format()` to write into strings.

```
# Using the fileinput module we can open a file and write to it using stdout.
import fileinput
# using stdout we avoid the formatting of print, and avoid extra newlines.
import sys

filename = 'testfile'
params = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
# Build the new replacement line.
newline = '{0}_{1}_(2)_{3}.hgx'.format(filename, params[0], params[1], params[2])

for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1):
  if line.startswith('MY_FILE'):
     sys.stdout.write('MYFILE = {0}\n'.format(newline))
  else:
     sys.stdout.write(line)
```

This should replace any line starting with `MYFILE` with the line`MYFILE = 'testfile_foo_bar_baz.hgz`

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on `' '`, which is before the `=`, but not adding another `=` back.  There are many ways you can do this, but the easiest may be to simply add the `=` back in:

```
f.write(line.rsplit(' ', 1)[0] + "='%s'\n" % add_name)
```

Another, cleaner, way to do it would be to use `replace`:

```
f.write(line.replace(filename, new_name))
```

As an aside, you can write the first line much better as:

```
add_name = '%s_%s_%s_%s.hgx' % (filename, para1, para2, para3)
```